# Why this code is exceeding time limit? Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters

Tags: c++, string, substring

Given a string S, I have to find the length of its longest substring that does not have any repeating characters. I came up with a code but it was exceeding time limit. I couldnt find where. Surprisingly, I came to GFG to find a similar code. As it was published, I tried this code(though my code had the same logic). Even this GFG code is exceeding time.

```
int longestUniqueSubsttr(string s)
{
    
    // Creating a set to store the last positions 
    // of occurrence
    map<char, int> seen ;
    int maximum_length = 0;

    // Starting the initial point of window to index 0
    int start = 0;

    for(int end = 0; end < s.length(); end++) 
    {
        
        // Checking if we have already seen the element or
        // not
        if (seen.find(s[end]) != seen.end())
        {
            
            // If we have seen the number, move the start
            // pointer to position after the last occurrence
            start = max(start, seen[s[end]] + 1);
        }

        // Updating the last seen value of the character
        seen[s[end]] = end;
        maximum_length = max(maximum_length, 
                             end - start + 1);
    }
    return maximum_length;
```

input: geeksforgeeks

output: 7 (eksforg)

Does anyone know why its happening?

Comment: `map<char, int> seen` is very slow in comparison with `char seen[CHAR_MAX]`

Comment: `end` is a terrible name for a string index variable!

Answer (score 0):

Using a `map` is slower than accessing an array, as indicated in a comment.

The corresponding complexity is O(n log n), as each checking in the `map`is O(logn).

With an array, complexity is O(n).

Here is a possible implementation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int longestUniqueSubsttr(const std::string& s) {
    
    // Creating a set to store the last positions 
    // of occurrence
    std::vector<int> seen (256, -1);
    int maximum_length = 0;

    // Starting the initial point of window to index 0
    int start = 0;
    for(int last = 0; last  < s.length(); ++last) {    
        // Checking if we have already seen the element or not
        if (seen[s[last]] != -1) {
            // If we have seen the number, move the start
            // pointer to position after the last occurrence
            for (int i = start; i < seen[s[last]]; ++i) {
                seen[s[i]] = -1;
            }
            start = seen[s[last]] + 1;
            seen[s[last]] = last;
        } else {
        // Updating the last seen value of the character
            seen[s[last]] = last;
            maximum_length = std::max(maximum_length, last - start + 1);
        }
    }
    return maximum_length;
}

int main () {
    std::string s = "abcabcdxby";
    auto ans = longestUniqueSubsttr (s);
    std::cout << "input = " << s << "\n",
    std::cout << "max length = " << ans << "\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```